# How to remove bad portlet from the page in Liferay?

Tags: liferay, portlet

I have my portlet damaging page, so dragging controls are not available. How can I remove such a portlet from the page?

How to reinit page layout or something?

**UPDATE 1**
Have totally removed portlet web-app from Liferay installation directory and now have a dimmed text "This portlet has been undeployed. Please redeploy it or remove it from the page."

Without any buttons to remove it :)

Comment: Which Liferay version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify database directly. In layout table find your page then in column typesettings delete your portlet id (just portlet id).

Comment: Modifying things in the database directly is for me only an option when all else fails. There might be something associated with the table that must also be modified.... etc.

Comment: Maybe all else failed... Do you know what is "something" that is associated, and what "etc" in this specific question/answer are? Answer is perfectly valid, whether you would you use it is up to you.

Answer (score 2):

Use Firebug, browse to the portlet. You'll see the close icon. Grab its source and enter it in the browser address bar and hit enter!

Comment: Somehow it is not there. My portlet is disabling everything.

Comment: worked for me in Chrome Dev Tools... click elements tab, expand class="portlet-topper", expand "portlet-topper-toolbar", expand class "portlet-close" and click the href in there.

Answer (score 0):

Take care editing the table, because some clients like MySQL Workbench don't retrive all the data in the longtext fields and you can corrupt the record, so the page will fail.

Regards!